# UIRemoteNotification received, but disappears when READ on other device

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I discovered this feature recently, wondering it's a new feature or not.

When I received a push notification (UIRemoteNotfication) from an app (ex. Gmail) on the lock screen.

If I open the mail from GMAIL web on computer, or open the mail using Airmail, the notificaton on my phone will disappear few seconds after.

I read the https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html document, but didn't found any reference about this feature.

Did anyone know about this feature? 
Thank you!

---

I've recorded a demo video: http://youtu.be/SHDJJnyWRec
When I read email on my mac, the notification just disappears, it knows this notficaiton has been read from other place...any reference of this feature?

Comment: Is this your need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications

Comment: @Scott Unfortunately not :(, but I've recorded a demo video, you can see it.

Comment: It's called Silent Push Notification. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986886/how-does-facebook-messenger-clear-push-notifications-from-the-lock-screen-if-you. By the way, your video is private.

Comment: @Scott Wow, thanks! Scott. Will you reply as answer? I'll choose you as the correct answer?