# How to deal with push notifications with different levels of urgency? Android and iOS comparison

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, notification-channel

I have an application both on Android and iOS. We are currently reworking our notifications and grouping them into categories with similar urgency and frequency. We want to give users some sort of control of the less priority notifications.

My main point would be to compare both platforms to understand how to implement the same result with the different tools provided.

These would be my main goals:

1. Separate notifications in 3 categories: high, medium, low;
2. Users can disable push notifications for low urgency notifications;
3. Users can customize how they want to see medium urgency notifications;
4. User should not disable high urgency notifications nor customize the way they are shown;

Having stated this, I have the following questions...

**1. How can we separate notifications into categories on iOS?**

Android has [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) that allows us to group similar notifications. iOS doesn't seem to have a similar feature. However, iOS has time-sensitive notifications and Critical Alerts notification that could solve 1, 3 and 4 for iOS. Would that be an appropriate approach for iOS?

**2. If possible to separate iOS notifications into groups on, is it possible to have insight whether the user has change the setting for each group in the system?**

*This is more like a follow up question for the above one... again, I think this is easily achievable on Android with the channels but on iOS this is not that clear.*

**3. Does Android has something comparable to iOS's critical alerts?**

With Android's [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) I can achieve 1, 2, and even 4 but, I'm no iOS user and so I'm not sure how critical alerts on iOS behave. Having said that, I'm not sure how I could achieve the same level of urgency on Android with [high-priority notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/time-sensitive#create-high-priority-notification).

Comment: Critical Alerts require an entitlement that you'd need special approval from Apple to get. I understand they don't even issue it for demos. "Priorities" are something you'd have to implement yourself with different [`UNNotificationCategory` types that you define](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory)

Comment: I'm aware of the special approval from Apple and we are planing on applying for that.

Comment: You can include a [`thread-id`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1) to have iOS group related notifications. You can use a [collapse id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454913/how-do-you-replace-one-push-notification-with-another-on-the-receiving-device) to replace an existing message